# Need help with the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help how to solve this equation: $$y' = 2y^2 - 2x^{2}y - 1$$
One solution is $y=x$.

I tried to place: $y=x+\frac{1}{z}$ but it didnt work

Comment: If *One solution is* $y=x$, then there are typo's in the equation.

Comment: someone help please?

Comment: yes. thenksyou.

Comment: Even it it looks "better", $y=x$ is not a solution.

Comment: yes this is a ricatti equation.. but i didnt succed to solve it

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Indeed, it may be a $+1$ instead of a $-1$ at the end of the equation.

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha suggests that the solution will contain Hypergeometric, Bessel and Gamma functions.

Comment: @projectilemotion. I totally agree with you.

Comment: Riccati please, no Ricatti that in Italian means something rather different (blackmails) and is not the correct name.

Comment: This is a [Riccati Equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation).

Comment: @Jon My apologies! I deleted my comment and replaced it with a new one with the correct spelling.

Comment: @projectilemotion Thanks!

Comment: As already pointed out, the equation should have $-1$ changed to $+1$ to have $x$ as an exact solution. In this case, one can set $y(x)=x+1/z(x)$ and get the linear equation $z'(x)=-2x^2z(x)-2x$ very easy to solve. Otherwise, Bessel functions enter into the solution that becomes unmanageable. One should also note that, using WKB approximation on the equation with the "wrong sign", one gets the approximate solutions $y(x)\approx (x^2+\sqrt{x^4+2x})/2x$ that reaches $x$ asymptotically.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $y=\dfrac{1}{u}$ ,

Then $y'=-\dfrac{u'}{u^2}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{u'}{u^2}=\dfrac{2x}{u^2}-\dfrac{2x^2}{u}-1$

$u'=u^2+2x^2u-2x$

Let $u=-\dfrac{v'}{v}$ ,

Then $u'=-\dfrac{v''}{v}+\dfrac{(v')^2}{v^2}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{v''}{v}+\dfrac{(v')^2}{v^2}=\dfrac{(v')^2}{v^2}-\dfrac{2x^2v'}{v}-2x$

$\dfrac{v''}{v}-\dfrac{2x^2v'}{v}-2x=0$

$v''-2x^2v'-2xv=0$